# css flexbox : equal space between elements except the first two of ul>li*7 list

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using css flex to render a simple ul>li*7 list.
I want the space between elements to be equal : I've set the parent justify-content to space-between.

However, the two first elements are icons without text, so I'd like them to stay on the far left.
With space-between, the first one is by default on the far left, that's ok.
How can I put the second one on the left too, keeping an equal space between the others ?

Code :

```
<ul>
    <li class="left"></li>
    <li class="left"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<style rel="stylesheet">
    ul {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .left {
        something to make elements stick on left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: can you add an example fiddl

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? used absolute positioning. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azGKba

Comment: I've just added a code example. @Justin, the result is the one I'm looking for except I'd like it not to depend on fixed width and margins...

Comment: So you want to use flex-grow/shrink so they scale?

Comment: well, in your example you set absolute positions so if the first element width changes, the absolute left parameter needs to be changed. This won't work for me as my li might have changing contents. I don't know how flex grow/shrink would change that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this will work your you, but you could try using `justify-content: flex-start;` and then giving all the `<li>`s that are not to the left `margin: auto;`.

```css
ul {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
li:not(.left) {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="left"></li>
    <li class="left"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```